# How to derivative the linear equation of matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the equation as

$$F(w,x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \left (  Y(x)-w^TA(x)\right)^2u_i(x)dx$$

In which, $w$ is column vector that independent on $x$, denotes $w=[w_1,w_2...,w_M]^T$

$A$ is column vector value that denotes $A(x)=[a_1(x),a_2(x),...,a_M(x)]^T$

$(.)^T$ is transpose operator. $Y(x)$ and $u_i(x)$,$A(x)$ are independent on $w$.

I want to perform derivative of $F(x,w)$ with respect to $w$. Could you see my answer and give me some suggestion that Is it correct?
$$\frac {\partial F(x,w)}{\partial w}=?$$

That is what I done

we see that $w^TA(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{M} w_ia_i$, then

$$\frac {\partial (w^TA)}{\partial w_i}=ai$$

For $i=1$ to $M$, hence 
$$\frac {\partial (w^TA)}{\partial w}=A$$

Hence, 
$$\frac {\partial F(w,x)}{\partial w}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \left ( Y(x)-w^TA(x)\right)u_i(x)\frac {\partial (w^TA)}{\partial w}dx$$
$$\frac {\partial F(w,x)}{\partial w}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \left ( Y(x)-w^TA(x)\right)u_i(x)A(x)dx$$

$$\frac {\partial F(w,x)}{\partial w}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \left ( Y(x)-w^TA(x)\right)A(x)u_i(x)dx$$

Because $w^TA(x)=A(x)w$ then

$$\frac {\partial F(w,x)}{\partial w}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \left ( Y(x)A(x)-A(x)A^T(x)w\right)u_i(x)dx$$
I'm wondering about the last two steps.

Comment: Everything looks fine, you only forgot a minus sign when differentiating $Y-wA$. In addition I'put into parentheses $A^Tw$ to make clear it's a scalar.

Comment: @Aretino: Thank you. I update it base on your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this way to get the derivative:
\begin{eqnarray}
D_wF(h)(w,x)&=&\frac{d}{dt}F(w+th,x)\bigg|_{t=0}\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} \frac{d}{dt}\left[(Y(x)-(w+th)^TA(x))^2\right]u_i(x)\bigg|_{t=0}dx\\
&=&-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{x \in \Omega} (Y(x)-w^TA(x))h^TA(x)u_i(x)dx.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks, Finally, It will be same my result. Is it right. Because your result appears $h$ term

Comment: It is Gâteaux derivative.